# Not able to access Views folder using Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I have two partial views and based on the browsers width i have to call one over the other, but when i try to call the partial view which is placed inside the Views Folder, i am not able to call the page and i am getting an error like this
[image]

I am able to access the html files if i place it inside the Contents folder but i am not able to access the same files when i place it inside the Views folder.
here is my code

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'Views/Shared/UserManagementPopUp.cshtml',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
            },
            error: function () {
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

**I have tried** adding this in the views web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

can anyone help me understand what exactly am i doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: The Shared directory is apparently not visible to a controller. You must place your file in Views/Home for example and add an ActionResult in the controller public ActionResult UserManagementPopUp()
        {
            return View();
        }
or create a new controller ManagementController.cs (for example) and put the file UserManagementPopUp.cshtml  in the directory Views/Management and add an ActionResult in the controller

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette can' i directly try to access the partial view in the views folder by giving the full path like eg(../Views/Shared/MyPage.cshtml) insteda of calling it from the controller? does the MVC allow such methods?

Comment: No, it must be that a controller knows where to find the file. When a user enters a URL into the browser, MVC determines the path of the controller and the controller execute the appropriate action method to handle the request.

Comment: The point is that the .cshtml files contain (usually) enriched html code that need to be translated to *real* HTML code. This is what the MVC framework is doing while processing the controller/view logic. If you want to simply display a HTML page, put it into a separate folder or use a controller to display your .cshtml file.